# PowerShell to add date to all filenames in a folder

Tags: powershell, automation, dry-run

I have three files named First_File.txt Second_File.txt Thrid_File.txt in a folder named C:\01Source
I want to add the current date to the filenames so they look like this:
First_File_20220909.txt

The terminal output is this:

> What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\01Source\First_File.txt Destination: C:\01Source\First_File_20220909.txt".
> (runs for all three files names)

BUT... when I look in the C:\01Source folder the filenames are not changed, they are still First_File.txt

What did I miss?

This is my code:

```
$Path = "C:\01Source\"
write-host $Path
$curDateTime = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $curDateTime + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Comment: [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/whatif-confirm-and-validateonly-switches-exchange-2013-help) switch shows what it *would have* done if you ran the command without it.

Comment: One way to code in powershell is to download visualstudio code. Install the powershell extension. create a file called myscript.ps1 in a folder. And test the script using the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Abraham Zinala](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/whatif-confirm-and-validateonly-switches-exchange-2013-help) has provided the crucial pointer:

- **The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above only *previews* the operation without actually performing it.**

  - The purpose of using `-WhatIf` is to do a "dry run" that allows you to confirm that the command will work as intended when actually run, so as to prevent potentially costly mistakes.
- That is, the message you saw, `What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on ...`, tells you what *would* happen *if you re-ran the command WITHOUT `-WhatIf`*.

  - Therefore, you simply need to remove `-WhatIf` from the end of your `Rename-Item` call in order to perform actual renaming.

---

Note that **not *all* cmdlets support `-WhatIf`** - generally only those with potentially destructive consequences.

Cmdlets that support `-WhatIf` also support the [common `-Confirm` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm) (and vice versa), which requests that a per-input-object confirmation prompt be shown before processing.

To see whether a given cmdlet supports `-WhatIf` / `-Confirm`, look for `[-WhatIf]` / `[-Confirm]` in the [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) output by [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) or when you pass the `-?` switch, or when you use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `-Syntax`; e.g., `Rename-Item -?` or `Get-Command -Syntax Rename-Item`.
Alternatively, as you're typing a command, try *tab completion* (type something like `-Wha`, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see if it auto-completes to `-WhatIf`).

---

It is possible to **implement support for `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` in your own functions and scripts**, as long as they are [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) ones, as the following example shows:

```bash
function Remove-Foo {
  # * "SupportsShouldProcess" is what activates -WhatIf / -Confirm support.
  # * The "ConfirmImpact" value determines whether confirmation prompts are shown
  #   by default, relative to the $ConfirmPreference preference variable.
  #   Setting the value to 'High' would prompt *by default*.
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]
    $FooId
  )

  process {
    # $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess() either shows the conformation prompt (with -Confirm)
    # or prints a what-if message (with -WhatIf).
    # If $false is returned, the confirmation prompt was declined, or a what-if message was printed,
    # so no further action should be taken for this object.
    if ($false -eq $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($FooId)) {
      return # Do nothing (else)
    }
    # Regular processing.
    "Removing $FooId..."
  }

}
```

Sample call after defining the above function:

```bash
PS> 'foo', 'bar' | Remove-Foo -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove-Foo" on target "foo".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove-Foo" on target "bar".
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **-WhatIf** from the last line. Your code should like this below:

```
$Path = "C:\01Source\"
write-host $Path
$curDateTime = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $curDateTime + $_.Extension }
```